# unreported exception UnknownHostException; must be caught or declared to be thrown during global declaration

Tags: java, exception, jframe, global-variables, netbeans-8

I am trying to declare one global variable in a class, whenever I create simple variables like `int i;` , they are created easily, but when I try to create an object like `Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3",4917);` it gives the error that I have mentioned. I know that its wants me to handle exception, but no syntex is working at this part of the program, `try` and `catch` says illegal type of start.

This might get solved by correct syntex required to be applied. Please help. Thanks.

Here is my code..

```
public class NumberAdditionUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3",4917); 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NumberAdditionUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It's not asking you to throw an exception, it's *telling* you that it throws an exception (which you are not handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the constructor of `Socket` can throw an exception, and you need to handle it somehow.

There are a couple easy ways to do this.

One is by creating a no-arg constructor, and initializing `socket` there.  You can then either handle the exceptions there, or declare that you throw them and let the instantiating code deal with it:

```
Socket socket;
public NumberAdditionUI() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 4917);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
// OR
public NumberAdditionUI() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 4917);
}
```

Another way to do this is to use an [initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

```
Socket socket;
{
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 4917);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for creating the Socket you are using throws exceptions
`UnknownHostException` and 'IOException'. These must always be inside a try catch or must be catched atleast some where in the flow of control.

But in your case you are declaring it in global context and you cannot handle this exceptions like this case.

the constructor looks like this

```
public Socket(String host,
      int port)
       throws UnknownHostException,
              IOException
```

See the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)